# Accessing a file with a local Node.js test server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access a arbitrary html file on my computer using a local node.js server. The problem is whenever I try and access the file with the "fs" module, the "data" variable is coming up undefined.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs= require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log(process.cwd());
    //because the response is in the callback of readfile it will only serve data after fs.readfile loads
    fs.readFile('Desktop\Practice_page\HTML\PRAC.html',function(err, data){ 
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
       if(data===undefined)
            res.write("frick");
            else
            res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

My working directory is C:\Users\MYC, so the relative path should be Users\MYC\Desktop\ ect. Is there a problem with my syntax, or am I using the file system module wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what `err` contains? Have you tried with full path?

Comment: Yeah, I used an absolute path with the \ character doubled and it worked. Sorry for the stupid question :/

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong. You have to pass an absolute path using `__dirname`.

```
fs.readFile( __dirname + '\Practice_page\HTML\PRAC.html' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use absolute path. Either use the path module or add in the full directory listing.